# Need an help for re-writing an postgresql query as Yes or No

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query as shown below,

```
select hr_employee_id, hr_firstname, hr_age, hr_desig, hr_gender, hr_yrs_exp,
       hr_doj, hr_dol, hr_typeofemp, hr_highqual
From hr_employee
order by hr_firstname
```

where i have to represent the data as shown in image below:
[image: Data should be get displayed as shown]

Where i had got struck in re-writing the query to display the data as YES or NO based on the fields which i have.

In the query i have two dates joining date and leaving date, by comparing with that dates ,

1. I have to display the employee is present last year (Yes or NO).
2. Currently working with the institution (Yes or NO).

Comment: Hi, I advise you to read about "case when" statements which you can use in your query to achieve the result you are after.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You say you have two dates in the query, but I don't see any date fields in your query. Are these columns present in the same `hr_employee` table or do we have to join to them? Are they both present in the same record? I think it would help tremendously if you could add some sample data to your question and your desired results. I feel something like `CASE WHEN CURRENT_DATE between joindate and leavingdate THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END` would solve one of these two requirements.

Comment: And perhaps `CASE WHEN daterange(date_trunc('year', now()) - INTERVAL '1' YEAR < leavingdate AND date_trunc('year', now()) > joindate THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END` would potentially solve the first requirement (present last year).

Comment: Assuming the employee is still with the institution... what does leave date look like? Is it null?

Comment: Yes,joining date and leaving date in the same table of hr_employee as represent above doj(dateofjoining) and dol(dateofleaving).If there is nothing mentioned about leaving date it represents as employee still working the institution.

Comment: hi JNevill,Thank's for your response,can in know where the date range function ends and if the leaving date is null what can be the case condition.